# Ephemeral Jenkins Pipeline Jobs from Github and Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have automated Jenkins master and slaves deployment and redeployment successfully.

I know how to manually create pipeline jobs and add github repos to use their Jenkinsfiles for the steps.

**my issue is** *how can I automate the pipeline jobs addition to jenkins after its been destroyed and redeployed without having to manually create the pipeline jobs and point to Jenkinsfile each time.*

I have seen this done before in a container environment with chef and docker when redeployed or updated it re-adds all the pipelines automatically again.

I want to not use the UI at all only to confirm job status progress and verify settings.

Comment: Likely the container was binding the volume mount for the jobs, so that when the container was re-created, the jobs were never destroyed, but rather "discovered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [JobDSL Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl) to create jobs, using a seed job to create them on initial Jenkins startup. The [Jenkins Configuration-as-Code plugin](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/) can be used to setup any other configuration outside the jobs.